# Convert changing text to mesh

Tags: python, export, unity, .fbx, text-object

I wrote a code in Blender which changes the shown text during the course of an animation for explanation of the animation.
Sadly, my version of blender is not recognized by my version of Unity.

- When I export my file as .fbx, only the text at the frame it was made on is shown.
- Normally I would export as .mdd, but that is not possible for text.
- When I try an .abc export, the text does not update.

Can I for each if statement add keyframes and change the text automatically to a new mesh for instance?

The code I have now is:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = scene.objects['Text']


def recalculate_text(scene):
    frame = scene.frame_current
    
    if frame in range(5,75):
        obj.data.body = 'Incision ulna'
        
    if frame in range(75, 120):
        obj.data.body = 'Osteotomy of ulna'  
        
    if frame in range(120, 146):
        obj.data.body = 'Insert plate on ulna' 
    
    #and so on...
        
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(recalculate_text)
```

Comment: i am not sure whether converting to mesh solves your problem alone, because if you convert it, you cannot "assign" a new text...

Comment: That is why I wanted to assign a duplicate and keyframes for each if-statement, such that I end up with multiple meshes containing text. Would that work?

Comment: to be honest...i tried this over an hour...and created a mesh each frame (although the text did not change every frame) and keyframed render_viewport/render and it "worked" in blender, but exporting to fbx needed more than minutes (i think it crashed but because i am impatient i shut down blender)....and i'm not sure whether fbx can export/import render_viewport and i think it cannot...